# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, browser-automation

My seleinum webdriver is not launching browser, getting error frequently.

Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

Alternative solution,please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For chrome version `116` and above, you need to upgrade selenium to `v4.11.0` if you are using Java/C# binding. And upgrade to `v4.11.2` if you are using Python binding.

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium Team changed how they package drivers recently. See https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ and their blog post on it: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/

The Selenium Team recently published new releases to support those changes, which are part of the `4.11` milestone: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/milestone/12?closed=1 and they also had their own blog post on it: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/

The short version is this: Upgrade to the latest version of selenium in your respective language bindings, and then things should start working again.